# Which runs first in bash? lexer, or expander?

Tags: bash, parsing, lexer, expander

I am trying to understand bash's parser and lexer mechanism. (My ultimate goal is implementing a bash-like shell).

**The first case**

```
$ test='o a'
$ ech$test
a
```

(^ edit: I removed double quotes for second line. My actual test case was that.)

The expander expanded the command and found the argument after expanding.
Expanded full command: **`echo a`**

So, I can assume that the lexer runs after the expansion operation because the bash understood that "echo a" is not a command name. "echo" is the command name, and "a" is an argument. (btw zsh don't that.)

**The second case**

```
$ test="'"
$ echo $test
'
```

Echo prints only one single quote. However, if we expand this string to: **`echo '`**, it is not a valid command because it has an unclosed quote. So, I can assume two things:

1. At first, the lexer understands what it is and expands after.
2. Actually, the value of the 'test' variable is not one single quote. Its value is exactly: `"'"`. So, in reality, we don't expand to `echo '` we expand to **`echo "'"`**, which is valid.

But the first assumption and the first test case's assumption do not coincide. So, I assume the second one.

**The third case**

```
$ test="'"
$ echo "$test"
'
```

Echo prints only one single quote again. However, (I assume) it expanded this string to: **`echo ""'""`**, which is invalid because we have an unclosed quote.

So, my question is: "How does the bash understand what I mean?"

Comment: Your code snippets have `“` and `‘` unicode characters. Bash uses `"` and `'` ascii. `Which runs first in bash? lexer, or expander?` Are you _actually interested only specifically in_ which of the case of bash runs first, or are you more interested what rules govern variable expansion?

Comment: In the test phase, I used `"` and `'`. I am actually interested only in when should I recognize what is an argument and what is a command name, etc. If recognize `ech$test` as a command name, my command is "echo a" and my shell will search "echo o" executable at where $PATH variable show.

Comment: Perhaps the following quotation from the bash man page helps: _The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); **word splitting**; and pathname expansion. .... After these expansions are performed, quote characters present  in  the  original  word  are  removed unless they have been quoted themselves (**quote removal**)_.

Comment: Yes, you're right about this page may help. Let me share here my ultimate understanding: 1. lexer tokenizes our input. The manual explicitly defines what a token is(2 Definitions). 2. expander expands variables. the manual explicitly defines the order of these expansion operations (3.5 Shell Expansions, as you mentioned). 3. splits words using the IFS variable. the manual explains word splitting explicitly (like every time) (3.5.7 Word Splitting). 4. removes quotes of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX specification includes a detailed description of the behavior of [the shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), including considerable detail about how it processes input. It begins with:

> The shell shall read its input in terms of lines. (For details about how the shell reads its input, see the description of `sh`.) The input lines can be of unlimited length. These lines shall be parsed using two major modes: ordinary token recognition and processing of here-documents.

It continues from there with details of how lines are tokenized.

Only after a line has been tokenized can any kind of substitution or expansion be performed, because only at that point can the shell recognize where substitutions and expansions are called for.

> **The first case**
>
> ```
> $ test='o a'
> $ ech"$test"
> a
> ```

I don't believe you.  I do not reproduce that result in Bash 4.3, nor do I expect to do. The POSIX specifications and the Bash manual are explicit and in agreement on this point: parameter expansions that occur inside double quotes are not subject to word splitting.

With respect to the order of command-line processing, what happens is that `ech"$test"` is recognized as a single token.  Parameter expansion, field splitting, and quote removal apply *to that token* ("word" in shell jargon), with the overall result that it expands to a single word `echo a`, which, by virtue of its position in the fully-expanded command line, is interpreted as a command name.

It would be different if you instead did

> ```
> $ ech$test
> ```

where the `$test` parameter expansion was not quoted.  I suspect that's what you actually did in Bash to get the output `a`.  In this case, the expansion of `$test` is not protected from word splitting, so after expanding the word to the (single) word `echo a`, that is split into two words at the space.  The result is `echo` as command name and `a` as its argument.

> **The second case**
>
> ```
> $ test="'"
> $ echo $test
> '
> ```

Yes, as the spec describes, quote characters are recognized during token recognition.  Quote characters introduced into a command by parameter expansion are significant only as themselves.

> 2. Actually, the value of the 'test' variable is not one single quote.

Yes, it is.  And this can be tested in a variety of ways, such as (your third case) `echo "$test"`, or `echo ${#test}`, or (in bash) `echo "${test:0:1}"`.

> Its value is exactly: `"'"`. So, in reality, we don't expand to echo `'` we expand to echo `"'"`, which is valid.

No, it isn't.  See above for the actual explanation of the behavior you observed.

Overall, I strongly recommend relying first and foremost on the **specifications** for the behavior you want to implement.  Experimenting is a fine way to try to clarify and solidify your interpretation of the specs, but it is a very unreliable way to determine the details of the required behavior.

Comment: Regarding "I don't believe you. I do not reproduce...". Yes, I didn't realize these quotes. I mean 'ech$test'. Sorry, I fixed it right now. The "Parameter expansion, field splitting, and quote removal apply to that token..." looks like the correct way to implement this bash. Tokenize->Expand->Split->Unquote

Comment: More or less, @Mister_Obliviate.  As I said, refer to the specifications.  But note also that when performing quote removal, you must avoid removing quotation marks *etc* that were introduced by expansions.  Only those that appeared in the original input are subject to removal.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer as others have said is the lexer. I just want to share an interesting bug I once had. I had a script like this:

```bash
foo() {
    shopt -s extglob
    # Code which uses extended globbing...
}

foo
```

It didn't work and it took me a long time to understand why. The reason was that extglob is a feature of the lexer, not the expander. By the time the function is called, its body has already been tokenized, hence activating extglob inside it won't change anything. So this is one experiment to answer your question.

Comment: Interesting. However, my implementation will be basic and won't include functions.

Comment: @Verpous Thank you for sharing. I would not have expected that. I could confirm that `f() { shopt -s extglob; echo /@(*); }` results in `bash: syntax error` while parsing (not executing) `f`. Surprisingly, enabling `globstar` *inside* a function works as one would assume naively. Due to the behavior for `extglob` I would have expected that `g() { shopt -s globstar; echo /tmp/**; }` would be parsed basically as `echo /tmp/*`, but it seems the parser keeps the `**` (even when globstar is disabled while parsing) and decides how to expand it during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

> Which runs first in bash? lexer, or expander?

Lexer. The input has to be tokenized. Only after tokenization, expansion can be executed, however context - double quotes vs here document vs backticks - is relevant for the expansions. This is also documented https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions :

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens.

In addition to above bash documentation, you might also want to read https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01 .

Comment: I have a Lexer currently. It recognizes tokens as:
(`ech$test` -> COMMAND)
(`echo a` -> COMMAND ARGUMENT)

If I expand after this phase, my command name won't be 'echo'. It will be 'echo a'. Just like I just entered `echo\ a` to prompt line. How can I implement it like bash?

Comment: `like bash?` Bash specifically uses https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/4b0f8ba28449c60d6b3436d0c98b14e016b232c2/parse.y#L438 YACC and BISON to generate the parsing. While I understand that you want to follow existing implementation, but note they are just very big. Dash is a much much smaller shell https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/parser.c . Overall, there is no simple "how can I implement it" answer. _You_ have to implement it, if you want to, it's not simple, it's very hard, and it will take _a lot_ of time to handle all the cases.

Comment: I am not good with lexing myself, I know there are very very good books on the topic that have been recommended to me on some occasions, but sadly I do not know them so I am not much help. Handling simple `"` `'` `|` is still a lot of work, and also handling `<` `<(..)` `<<EOF` is much much more.

Comment: `If I expand after this phase` The rules are described in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01 in particular in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02 . Escape character (backslash) is also documented https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01  and below is token recognition https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03 .

Comment: `If recognize ech$test as a command name`  Unquoted variable expansion `$test` undergoes word splitting and filename expansion. Word splitting splits the result of `$test` on spaces, so it becomes two _words_ `echo` and `a`.  After all expansions, then the simple command `echo` is executed (but it can't be a builtin now). There are rules, rules and more rules, and there is no simple answer except you'll just have to learn them.

Comment: Overall, maybe we are just using different terms. "Lexer" has to run first, to split into tokens. Then these tokens, _can be_ split into several more token or in less tokens, with expansions. it's not 1:1 relationship after lexing.

Comment: In the end, I agree with this: "It's not a 1:1 relationship after lexing.". I understand that Lexer must be split into tokens before expanding but the tokens are not ultimate until we expand it. Probably I'll use double lexer (or maybe we can call the second one, another thing). Lexing-> Expanding->Post-Lexing (to check if are there new tokens)

Comment: @Mister_Obliviate regarding *"If I expand after this phase, my command name won't be 'echo'"*. Perhaps you are forgetting about a bash/sh-specifc step that takes places *after* parsing. After everything is parsed and expanded, bash does *word-splitting*. This is a mechanism that is solely controlled by characters in the `IFS` variable. Symbols like ``"'`$(;&`` have no special meaning at that time anymore.